# How to calculate this contour integral $\oint_{|z-3|=2} \frac{\log z}{z+1} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$\oint_{|z-3|=2} \frac{\log z}{z+1} dz$$ 
Where $log$ denotes the natural logarithm.

I'm so confused with the fact that the function $f(z)=\frac{\log z}{z+1}$ has a singularity in $z=-1$ and the contour passes through it. I think I have to draw a new contour around this point, but appears this branch $<-\infty,0]$. Please guide trhough this problem.

Comment: The pole and branch point are outside the contour, so the integral is zero.

Comment: Indeed, $|z-3|=2$ is a circle with radius $2$ centered at (3,0), passing through $(1,0)$  and $(5,0)$, not even close to $(-1,0)$.

Comment: Ohh. Using Cauchy-Goursat theorem, I get it. Thanks.